# unprivileged or privileged malware for botnets

Tags: malware, ddos

For those malwares which are used to organize botnets to DDOS a website, they just need to send and receive HTTP packets. Do they need to be privileged?

If they dont need to be privileged, is it true that any unprivileged program I run on my machine could contain malicious code to DDOS a website with my bandwidth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, no, there is no need for administrative privileges for HTTP DoS, nor spamming nor pure UDP DoS (flooding UDP packets to the target in order to exhaust their bandwidth).

However, the compromised system may have a firewall or some other security software preventing the malware from doing its thing, in which case administrator privileges will be required for the malware to reconfigure the firewall to allow it to (D)DoS or spam.

Also, the malware may need administrator privileges to make itself launch on system boot.

For your second question, yes that's possible, but very unlikely. Most (if not all) programs you have on your machine come from an identifiable source (a person or a company), so there's no benefit for that person/company to put malicious code in his software, that will ruin their reputation, bring them lots of legal issues for no benefit at all.

On the other hand, if you run some random `.exe` found on a shady site then yes, it's possible and you should prepare for the worst. If you must use these shady programs, you better buy a throwaway laptop on which you don't have anything personal and disconnect it from the internet. Even if the program happens to contain malware, it will greatly reduce the damage it can do if the machine doesn't hold anything private and can't communicate with the network.

Answer (score 2):

Sending HTTP request packets doesn't requires any privilege. The main aim behind sending HTTP request is to force the server or application to allocate the maximum resource in response to a single request. Two type of request can be used GET and POST. HTTP GET request is used to request the static contents and POST is used to request the dynamic contents. To make the attack as havoc to the application the attacker uses POST request because it may uses parameters that can be used to trigger the complex server-side processing.

Since to perform the attack Network attack vector is required, so if a unprivileged program has flaw that can be exploited to send the requests.